# Why AFNetworking POST Multi-Part Request has to sync run on main queue?

Tags: ios, post, afnetworking, grand-central-dispatch, afnetworking-2

I check the AFNetworking codes for POST Multi-Part Request and find to my surprise that it has to sync run on main queue,

```
- (BOOL)transitionToNextPhase {
    if (![[NSThread currentThread] isMainThread]) {
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self transitionToNextPhase];
        });
        return YES;
    }
...
```

This is called when create AFHTTPBodyPart for POST Multi-Part Request

```
[manager POST:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileURL:filePath name:@"image" error:nil];
} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    ...
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    ...
}];
```

It was actually asked and answered at GitHub [issue #2006](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/2006) "I think that's there so the main thread will be used as a synchronization point. (To ensure that operations happen in the correct order, even if they're on different threads.)..."

I can understand operations need to run in serial order, but why in **main queue** ? Can't we just another dedicated queue for it?

I also added my question and a relatively easy way to reproduce deadlock to [issue #2481](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/2481)

Answer (score 1):

I can imagine problems scheduling the `NSInputStream` (see a bit later in the same routine) on the "current" run loop if you're on a background thread. You generally can't just schedule timers, connections, streams, etc., on a background thread without keeping the run loop alive somehow (cf. [`networkRequestThread`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFURLConnectionOperation.m#L172)). Also, there might also be subtle issues with input streams provided by app developer (via [`appendPartWithInputStream`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFURLRequestSerialization.m#L738)) expecting his input stream to be used from the main thread, too.

I suspect that Mattt concluded that it was going to be a lot of work to synchronize this behavior on any thread other than the main thread. Furthermore, there's little benefit moving this off the main thread (given that one should never block the main thread, anyway).

But you should just [create your own issue](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/new) and ask the author directly.

Comment: After think through your words I think it makes sense. Just like apple document said "You should never attempt to access a scheduled stream from a thread different than the one owning the stream’s run loop" So making it run in main thread is the simplest solution I guess. BTW, I did not open my own issue b/c as I had shown the question was asked and closed I just didn't get the answer completely.